# How can I display Google Analytics using the API in my website

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a website where buyers and sellers are logging in using their unique id. They will be visiting various product pages once logged in. Using Google Analytics API, I would like to display the details of each buyer or seller, with the time they spent in a product page, the pages they visited, etc., in my website backend.

However I am not able to get the UserID, which is important to display the user name and other information, using the google API code.

The same details are visible when I download the data as an excel sheet from google analytics dashboard.

Is there any restriction in APIs that the UserID will be not passed?
How we can achieve this otherwise?